# make a facet sorting records with dates with openrefine

Tags: openrefine

i have in a column, dates and time and the dates format looks like this:
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

example:

```
2019-07-08 12:33:59
```

how could i make a facet, that would filter records by year and month?
i.e. 2019 - 01 (January)
2019 - 02 (February)
etc

i have tried with makinh a custom text facet with `value.datePart("years")`, then again with `value.datePart("months")`, but i am getting an error for all records...
Also tried with `value.toDate("yyyy")` which seems to return only the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using OR 3.2, because version 3.1 had, I think, a problem with dates.

Then, you just have to extract the year and the month of your dates as a string:

```
value.toString('yyyy-MM')
```

You can find [here](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions) the list of pattern letters to express date parts.

Comment: used OR 3.2 beta, I do not kow if i miss something, but i tried adding a new column, value.toString('yyyy-MM') which gave me the error:
1. null Error: toString accepts an object and an optional second argument containing a date format string

Comment: How, this is probably because your 2019-07-08 12:33:59 is stored as a string (in black) and not as a date (in green). Can you try value.toDate().toString('yyyy-MM') ?

Comment: your guess was exact, the last expression did the job

Comment: there is a shortcut in the menu to transform strings to date : edit cells -> Common transforms --> to Date